# memory consumed by a string vector in c++

Tags: c++, memory, vector

i am creating a vector of strings in c++. What i need is total memory consumed in bytes by this vector.

Since the strings are of variable size, right now i am iterating through every vector element and finding its length then at the end i am multiplying this to size of char. What I need is a cleaner solution.

```
vector<string> v;
//insertion of elements
int len=0;
for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
                    len+=v[i].length();
int memory=sizeof(char)*len;
```

alternatively a solution to find the memory consumption of a string array would also do. let's say

```
string a[SIZE]
```

find number of bytes for a?

Comment: The total memory of a `std::string` is not just the sum of the `char`s, there is additional overhead in the class.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1. And `std::accumulate` clearly expresses an intent to accumulate things, such as lengths.

Comment: Depending on the implementation, `string` is stored differently. For example in VS, `string` has a 16 character buffer allocated statically that it uses for speed, then it uses dynamically allocated memory if you need more than 16 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rough estimate of the memory occupied by `std::vector<string>`:

```
      sizeof(std::vector<string>) // The size of the vector basics.
      + sizeof(std::string) * vector::size()  // Size of the string object, not the text
//  One string object for each item in the vector.
//  **The multiplier may want to be the capacity of the vector, 
//  **the reserved quantity.
      + sum of each string's length;
```

Since the `vector` and `string` are not fixed sized objects, there may be some additional overhead occupied by the dynamic memory allocations.  That is why this is an estimate.

**Edit 1:**
The above calculation assumes single character unit; not multibyte characters.

Comment: You also want to use `capacity` instead of `size()`. `size()` reflects the amount of memory that's actually in use, but `capacity()` reflects the amount of memory actually allocated.